# Returning more than one value on a conditional inner join statement (VBA/SQL)

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I'm quite new to VBA/SQL and I'm trying to execute a conditional inner join.

I have two tables with a column in common ("CRM" and "CodeCRM") and I would like to obtain email adresses from table2 ("Desks") when something is triggered (CodeBlocage = 101) in table1 ("Flux") in order to add it to an automatic outlook email.

```
Dim StrDestinataire As String
Select Case Strtable
   Case "Flux", "GAFIJOUR"

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Y As String
    Dim sSql As String

    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection


    sSql = "Select AddMailCRM from Desks Inner Join Flux on Desks.CODECRM = Flux.CRM WHERE Flux.CODEBLOCAGE = '101'"

    Set rs = cn.Execute(sSql)

    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        Y = rs.Fields("AddMailCRM").Value
    End If


    StrDestinataire =  Y

    cn.Close
```

Everything works great except that it should be returning more than one value for the email adress. Any leads?

Thank you

Comment: To get multiple rows from a Recordset you'll have to loop it (MoveNext etc.)

Comment: Thank you Andre. I have actually used the syntax Y = rs.GetString to get all the email adresses of the recordset. My problem now is that some of the email adresses appear in double. How could I delete the doubles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading out a recordset you have to loop through the records line by line. With your current code you are only looking at the first line.

Try something like this:

```
Dim results as New List(Of String)

While Not rs.EOF
    results.Add(rs.Fields("AddMailCRM").Value)
    rs.MoveNext()
End While

results = results.Distinct().ToList
```

The results variable will be a list of unique values

Comment: I have actually used the syntax Y = rs.GetString to get all the email adresses of the recordset. My problem now is that some of the email adresses appear in double. How could I delete the doubles?

Comment: I have edited the answer to result in a list of unique values by adding them to a List(Of String) and in the end running a .Distinct() on them

Comment: Couldn't make it work with the While but I used your idea of DISTINCT in my select statement and it all worked out with the rs.GetString. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

```
Dim StrDestinataire As String
Select Case Strtable
   Case "Flux", "GAFIJOUR"
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Y As String
Dim sSql As String

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection


sSql = "Select DISTINCT AddMailCRM from Desks Inner Join Flux on Desks.CODECRM = Flux.CRM WHERE Flux.CODEBLOCAGE = '101'"

Set rs = cn.Execute(sSql)

If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
    Y = rs.GetString
End If


StrDestinataire = Y

cn.Close
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-ad??d-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, tailor the post to the question